# lab.js jquery selection for different ie version

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm using LAB.js to load some Scripts:

```
$LAB
.script("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js").wait()
.script("script.js")
    .and_many_more_scripts;
```

As JQuery v2 doesn't support the IE8, I need some conditions to load Jquery 1.11 instead of the v2 if the user uses IE8.

Right now, I'm using something like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

But I don't know how to use that with LAB.js. Do I have to use a complete LAB-call for every case?

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script>
        $LAB
        .script("html5.js")
        .script("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js").wait()
        .script("script.js")
        .and_many_more_scripts;</script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]>
    <script>
        $LAB
        .script("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js").wait()
        .script("script.js")
        .and_many_more_scripts;
    </script>
```

Comment: Why not just use jQuery 1.11 regardless of which browser?

Comment: I can do that, but the question is the same, as I need to load html5.js for ie8 - which I don't need for newer browsers. So it is the same task.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up here looking for some other IE8 issue, hope you figured out your problem by now.

But just in case someone else needs, this worked for me:

```
$LAB.script((document.documentMode == 8) ? "IE8SCRIPTURLGOESHERE":"NOTIE8SCRIPTURLGOESHERE");
```

If you just need to target IE8 leave the `"NOTIE8SCRIPTURLGOESHERE"` value empty: ""